# Convert connection string from VB to C#

Tags: c#, connection

I am trying to convert the following in VB (which works fine):

```
DBConn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(GlobalVariables.strConnection).ConnectionString
```

To C#:

```
DBConn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(GlobalVariables.strConnection).ConnectionString;
```

However I get the following error in C#:

> Non-invocable member 'ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings' cannot be used like a method.

What then would be the proper way to convert to C# ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [`ConnectionStrings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) is a collection with an [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/) you have to use `[...]` in C#

```
DBConn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[GlobalVariables.strConnection].ConnectionString;
```

[Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.connectionstringsettingscollection.item?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#system-configuration-connectionstringsettingscollection-item(system-string)) the indexer you're using.

Answer (score 0):

In both VB and C# we use `( )` around arguments to methods, and the `(` after a word representing a method will cause the method to be run

---

In VB things that behave like arrays (arrays, lists, dictionaries etc) are indexed with the same `( )`

```
Dim arr = "a b c".Split()
Dim b = arr(1)
```

..but in c# we use `[ ]` for indexing

```
var arr = "a b c".Split();
var b = arr[1];
```

If you get "non invocable member cannot be used like a method" when converting VB to C#, check anywhere you've used `( )` that should be `[ ]`. An additional hint in VS2019+ is look at the color of the thing before the `(`; if it's a method it's yellow. Properties (that cannot be called) are white. Because `(` is only ever used for method calling in c#, and not for indexing, it's a mistake to put it next to a white thing